# Is there a driver for mysql on nodejs that supports stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures

I am looking for a mySQL driver for nodejs that supports stored procedures. http://nodejsdb.org/db-mysql/ that I have been using gives the error

PROCEDURE  can't return a result set in the given context

Comment: here is a sample http://pastebin.com/8sh1vXrP

Comment: You always have few more options, if in case you aren't able to crack this module, check https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-db-mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it works in [nodejs-mysql-native](https://github.com/sidorares/nodejs-mysql-native)

stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE test1p1()
  BEGIN
  SELECT 1+1;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

node.js script:

```
mysql = require('mysql-native');
var db = mysql.createTCPClient();
    db.auth('test', 'tester', ''); // db, user, password

db.query('call test.test1p1;').on('row', function(r) {
    console.log(r);
}).on('end', function() {
    console.log('OK!');
});
```

output:

```
{ '1+1': 2 }
OK!
```

Answer (score 13):

Felix Geisendörfer's [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql) supports stored procedures, but you need to end your stored procedure by `SELECT`ing a success/failure flag, then query it as you would a `SELECT` query. Here's how the stored procedure might look:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS MyProcedure //
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProcedure(IN param1 VARCHAR/*, My, Parameters, ... */)
BEGIN

    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND, SQLWARNING, SQLEXCEPTION SELECT 0 AS res;
    # My Queries etc. ...

    SELECT 1 AS res;

END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Your Node code would look something like this:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var client = mysql.createConnection({
    host    : '127.0.0.1',
    user    : 'username',
    password: 'password'
});
client.query('USE mydatabase');

var myParams = "'param1', 'param2', ... ";
client.query("CALL MyProcedure(" + myParams + ")", function(err, results, fields) {
    if (err || results[0].res === 0) {
        throw new Error("My Error ... ");
    } else {
        // My Callback Stuff ...

    }
});
```

Comment: You have got to be kidding with this string concatenation of parameter values. Do you want SQL Injection? This is how we get SQL Injection.

Comment: perhaps the example should be updated to show how to properly escape, e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values

Comment: You could simply escape by using  + client.escape(myParams) +

Answer (score 6):

[node-mysql](http://www.javascriptpoint.com/nodejs-mysql-tutorial-example/) driver work with stored procedure and its very simple just call your stored procedure with parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllStudent(id int)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM student where userid = id ;
END;
```

and in node just call

```
app.get('/sp', function (req, res, next) {
    connection.connect();
    connection.query('CALL GetAllStudent(?)',[req.body.id],function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).send(err);
        }
        res.status(200).send(rows);
    });

    connection.end();
});
```

this way no need to worry of sql injection.

[here](http://www.javascriptpoint.com/nodejs-mysql-tutorial-example/) is good tutorial on nodejs and mysql

Answer (score 1):

Although this has been answered, I'll contribute with my own version, hope it helps you and anyone else that stumbles upon this post

In your case, this is how I would, in a single file, do (the 2019 way, kinda...) what you're trying to achieve (no need for anything other then express framework and the default mysql package that mostly everyone uses)

First, install these two packages:

- express: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express
- mysql: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql

Second, create a stored procedure like so:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myProcedure //
CREATE PROCEDURE myProcedure()
  BEGIN
    SELECT 'hello from procedure' AS message;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

And finally, create a node js script, open it and write the following lines of code:

```
//handles the requests/responses in your API
const express = require('express');

//handles the mysql stuff 
const mysql = require('mysql');


const app = express(); //create your express based app

//database access config
const config = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  user: 'username',
  password: 'password'
  database: 'test-db'
}

//Example route(you can add more of these for POST, PATCH and so on)
//If you need other methods just change the 'app.get' to 'app.<method here>'.
app.get('/test-route', (req, res) => { 
  try
  {
    const dbConn = mysql.createConnection(config); //creates a connection with the config above
    dbConn.connect((err) => { //connect to the db
      if(err)//if the connection fails log and send a error response
      {
        console.log(`Error: ${err.stack}`);
        res.status(500).send({error: "Something went wrong."});
      }
      else
      {
        let stmt = `CALL myProcedure();`; //sql query for running the example procedure 

        //You don't need to wrap anything in a try catch block if you don't mind 
        //your app crashing if any mysql related errors occur.
        //Console.log isn't required either. 
        //Use these above only if you need.
        try 
        {
          dbConn.query(stmt, (err, rows) => {
            if(err)//if the query fails log and send a error response
            {
              console.log(`Error: ${err.stack}`);
              res.status(500).send({error: "Something went wrong."});
            }
            else
            {
              try
              {
                //closes the connection and sends the result of executing the procedure
                dbConn.end();
                res.send({message: rows[0][0].message});
              }
              catch(err)
              {
                console.log(`Error: ${err.stack}`);
                res.status(500).send({error: "Something went wrong."});
              }
            }
          });
        }
        catch(err) 
        {
          console.log(`Error: ${err.stack}`);
          res.status(500).send({error: "Something went wrong."});
        }
      }
    });
  }
  catch(err)
  {
    console.log(`Error: ${err.stack}`);
    res.status(500).send({error: "Something went wrong."});
  }
}

//this must always be your last line of code in order
//for you to be able to run your express app
app.listen(5555, () => console.log('Server running...\nListening on port: 5555'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting multiple solutions together for completeness

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetStudent(id int)
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM student where userid = id ;
END;
```

Node.js and Express code:

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require("mysql");
var

app = express();

var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 100,
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'demo'
});

app.get('/pool', function (req, res) {

    var studentId = req.body.id;

    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        // connected! (unless `err` is set)
        if (err) {
            res.status(400).send(err);
        }
        connection.query('CALL GetStudent(?)',[studentId], function (err, rows, fields) {
             connection.release();
             if (err) {
                res.status(400).send(err);
            }
            res.status(200).send(rows);
        });     
    });
});

app.listen(4000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running.. on Port 4000');
});
```

(Source credits: Pushker Yadav and "http://www.javascriptpoint.com/nodejs-mysql-tutorial-example/")