# How do I call MySql procedures from Node JS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I want to call a stored procedure from [MySql node](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql):

How do I call it? The documentation says:

```
You can call stored procedures from your queries as with any other mysql driver. If the stored procedure produces several result sets, they are exposed to you the same way as the results for multiple statement queries
```

I tried searching for it on internet but got very old results which do not work anymore.

I tried:

```
connection.query('procedure_name()', {84,Bhuwan}, function(err, result) {
    connection.destroy();
    if (err)
      throw err;
    callback(err, result);
});
```

But I am getting error.

Can anyone provide a proper syntax for it??

Comment: What is the error? Also did you try adding `?` placeholders in the query string for the `[84,Bhuwan]` values that are to be included in the query?

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546956/is-there-a-driver-for-mysql-on-nodejs-that-supports-stored-procedures

Answer (score 9):

You have to use 'call' command and if you have parameters to pass to the query, you need to add '?' marks. Check the code.

```
connection.query("call procedure_name(?,?)", [param1, param2], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("err:", err);
    } else {
        console.log("results:", result);
    }

});
```

Comment: What changes if you have an OUT parameter?