# First time working with Stored Procedures

Tags: javascript, node.js, stored-procedures

This is my first time working directly with Stored Procedures and I need to know how to accommodate the params in a Node model.

The DB guys send me this

```
USE [Some_Dev]
GO

DECLARE    @return_value int,
        @Authenticated bit,
        @CustomerId int,
        @LoginStatus tinyint

EXEC    @return_value = [theDB].[spLogin_Customer]
        @Login = N'wilsonTest2',
        @Password = N'xXx21458',
        @Authenticated = @Authenticated OUTPUT,
        @CustomerId = @CustomerId OUTPUT,
        @LoginStatus = @LoginStatus OUTPUT

SELECT    @Authenticated as N'@Authenticated',
        @CustomerId as N'@CustomerId',
        @LoginStatus as N'@LoginStatus'

SELECT    'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I am using [mssql](https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#cfg-basic)

so, I am creating a login, the main requirement is to call this SP only in the model, anywhere else. But I don't have an idea where to start from.

Can someone gives me a hand?

I am here because you can't see much information about SP in the internet. So I need to clarify this with your help.

*EDIT*
here is what I have so far

```
import sql from 'mssql';

export default () => {
  cons config = {
    user: 'Marcelo',
    password: '54321@A',
    server: '111.111.111.1',
    database: 'Some_Dev'
  }

  let connection = new sql.Connection(config, function(err) {
    let request = connection.request();
    if (err) {
      cb(err);
    }
    request.input('Login', sql.VarChar(100));
    request.input('Password', sql.VarChar(100));
    request.output('Authenticated');
    request.output('CustomerId', sql.Int);
    request.output('LoginStatus', sql.Int);
    request.execute('[dbo].[spLogin_Customer]', function(err) {
      if (err) {
        cb(err);
      }
      connection.close();
      cb(null);
    })
  });
};
```

Comment: can you provide your model so far?

Comment: @ibiza see the update

Answer (score 0):

You might need [node-mysql2](https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2)

See [Is there a driver for mysql on nodejs that supports stored procedures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546956/is-there-a-driver-for-mysql-on-nodejs-that-supports-stored-procedures)